Missing link in the FAQ/help center
The help page for "What topics can I ask about here?" says:

You might want to read this article on writing the perfect question – originally for Stack Overflow, but relevant here too.

However there is no link to the article on writing the perfect question.  I'm pretty sure it is referring to http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx  (Why?  Because that was the link that was used in the earlier draft for this part of the FAQ.)
Can we get the link added to that help page?

Done!  Thanks for pointing that out.
